# Show that $f$ is convex if and only if $f(x) \leq \dfrac{1}{2h} \int_{-h}^{h} f(x+t) dt$ for every $[x-h, x+h] \subseteq (a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I have to show that a continuous function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ has the property of convexity if and only if
\begin{align}f(x) \leq \dfrac{1}{2h} \int_{-h}^{h} f(x+t) dt \end{align}
for every $[x-h, x+h] \subseteq (a,b)$.

I have already proven, in the context of a different exercise, that a function is convex if and only if it can be written in the form
\begin{align}
f(x) = f(c) + \int_{c}^{x}g(t) dt, \ x,c \in (a,b).
\end{align}

In order to achieve the aforementioned, I have tried changing the variable inside of the integral, to no avail. I also have no way of coming up with the inequality.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A proof for the “interesting” direction (if $f$ satisfies the integral inequality then it is convex) is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/974238/42969

Comment: In the "different exercise," $g$ has to be nondecreasing, right?

Comment: @angryavian that's correct

Comment: @MartinR many thanks for the link, I will take a look and if I am satisfied will close the question.

Comment: @MartinR I have looked at the link for the "interesting" direction but I do not understand what you mean when you say that if the integral inequality is satisfied then convexity is proven. Could you elaborate?

Comment: It is shown in https://mat$h.stackexchange.com/q/974238/42969 that if $f$ is convex and satisfies $f(x)\leq \frac{1}{2h}\int_{-h}^h f(x+t)dt$ for all $x$ and for all $h > 0$ then $f$ is convex. That is one direction of your “if and only of” question.

Comment: @MartinR let me rephrase. I understand the $(\impliedby)$ part of the link provided (typo btw). 

You said that it's trivial to prove the $(\implies)$ part, but I cannot see it. That's what I am asking you to clarify.

Comment: @algevristis: Let $c$ be a [subderivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative) of $f$ at $x$, then integrate the inequality $f(t) - f(x) \ge c (t-x)$.

Comment: @algevristis: Or just $\int_0^h (f(x+t) +f(x-t) - 2f(x)) \, dx \ge 0$.

Comment: @MartinR Presumably you meant integrate $f(x+t)-f(x) \ge ct$?

Comment: @copper.hat: Integrate $f(t) - f(x) \ge c (t-x)$ over $[x-h, x+h]$, or integrate $f(x+t)-f(x) \ge ct$ over $[-h, h]$, whatever you prefer :)

Comment: @MartinR I'm just being a pedant.

Comment: As a companion to Martin's solution, note that the interval $G= [ \lim_{h \uparrow 0} {f(x+h) - f(x) \over h}, \lim_{h \downarrow 0} {f(x+h) - f(x) \over h}]$ is non empty because $f$ is convex (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_one_variable), and for any $g \in G$ we have $f(x+t)-f(x) \ge gt$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f:(a, b) \to \Bbb R$ is convex and $[x-h, x+h] \subset (a, b)$ then
$$
 \int_{x-h}^{x+h} f(t) \, dt - 2 h f(x) = \int_{-h}^{h} \bigl(f(x+t)- f(x)\bigr) \,  dt \\
= \int_0^h \bigl(f(x+t) + f(x-h) - 2f(x) \bigr) \, dt \ge 0 \, .
$$

This proves one direction of the equivalence. For the other direction see for example [Continuous functions satisfying a condition to be convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974238/continuous-functions-satisfying-a-condition-to-be-convex) .